# Unpickling stack underflow error occurs when sending objects through socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, pickle, python-sockets

I'm trying to send an object from server to client through socket. The problem is no matter how I try, it is giving me the unpickling stack underflow error. I have experimented with buffer size: made it larger than what's necessary, made it the same size as the initial buffer. Also, I found that the serialized data that is sent from the server and received in the client side is exactly same. But whenever I try to unpickle it on the client side, it gives me the error. Can anyone help, please?

Here's the Game class for clarity:

```
class Game:
def __init__(self, game_id):
    self.id = game_id
    self.is_ready = False
    # game board object
    self.board = None
    # game dice object
    self.dice = None
    # list of game player objects
    self.players = []
    self.turn = 0
    self.winner = None
    self.last_rank = 0
```

Here, board, dice, and players are objects that this class is dependent on. I've experimented with sending the game object without adding these other objects and surprisingly it works.

The code on the server side:

```
game = games[game_id]
game.initialize_game() client.sendall(pickle.dumps(game))
```

The server can unpickle its own pickled data. I've printed the serialized data on both the client and server end. It's exactly the same. The error occurs only when I try to unpickle it on the client end.

```
game = pickle.loads(client.recv(2048))
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Is the pickled object less than 2048 bytes?

Comment: Yes... it's less than 2048 bytes